# I need to create a form with 2 parts. first part answers are received ONLY if second part answers were not completed

Tags: jquery, ajax, webforms

I basically need to have first part be a simple name / email field.. then a button says Next.
Then second part has about 10 more fields and then a submit.

I am trying to create this so that in the event the second part makes someone turn away, I still receive the first part. BUT if they fill out the second part I get all of it.

Please I'm pulling out my hair!

(I can make the form, my question is how to submit first part IF second part is not finished)

Comment: I am having a hard time visualizing how to in essence "hold part 1 data" while the user is either signing up with part 2 or leaving during part 2. then sending either part 1 by itself, or both 1& 2 if user completes full form. .... the idea comes from this website here: http://buymydreamhouse.com/ which dumps into a crm.. but without a CRM how can this be done?

Comment: If you submit a form and it takes you to another page, the variables from the form will be stored in a php variable called $_POST, and you access a variable by using $_POST['my_var_name'];

Answer (score 0):

Is there any problem in inserting 1st part on the click event of Next button.
If there is not, then it is the easiest way. I dnt think there is any other way because if a user fills 1st part and close the browser or tab then How do you get the data.

Comment: I do not understand this, I have only made forms before using standard html elements with some very basic jquery i have taken from other sites for effect. I am not a coder.

Answer (score 0):

Is "next" a javascript button/event or does it take you to a new php page?

If it takes you to a php page, it's simple. Just save the data at the top of the second page.

However, if "next" just displays more fields, you might be able to use jquery to post the data to a page, say "save.php", so the question is: How does your next button work? Can we see the example?

Comment: I currently do not have this built as I am still trying to work out the logic. So I do not know. what is the best way in your opinion to start from scratch on this?

Comment: Make a two-page form. On page one, add the easy stuff in a form, have it direct to pageTwo.php, and at the top of pageTwo.php, save the data from the first form, then show the the second form.

Comment: if they do not submit page 2 will i receive the data from page 1?

Comment: Yes, they should, if you save the data at the top of pageTwo.php. It all depends on how you plan to save the data, but a two-page solution should work.

Comment: How would you go about saving this data? I was trying to do all this wihtout a database and have the submission sent as a single email. Am I going to need a database for this to work? (by the way thank you for helping me, I appreciate it very much)

Comment: Well, you would use php and POST to get the data, and make the form: `<form action='pageTwo.php' method='POST'>(some stuff)</form>`. In php you can get the variables by name. Please google "php post tutorial" for much more information. Once you get the data on pageTwo.php, you can do whatever you want with it, such as sending an email or saving it to a database or local text file. Good luck!